# Looking for Power Bank with "Always-On-Feature"

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, power

I want to build a mobile weather station with an Arduino and some sensors. I want to use a power bank as power source. The Powerbank should support "Always-On", because weather data should not be measured continuously. This means that almost no current flows between the time intervals. Common power banks switch off automatically when the current flow is low.

I don't want to connect an additional device or electronic component to increase the power consumption. So I need a power bank that doesn't switch off even when the current flow is low.

During my search I found the Powerbank "V44 USB Battery Pack" from Voltaic. Unfortunately I cannot buy them in Germany.
https://www.voltaicsystems.com/v44

Can anyone recommend an alternative?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use a straight battery then?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  There is a great tour available at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour that shows how to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Lithium cell based powerbanks use a boost converter to boost the voltage from the Cell to the 5V for the USB. They turn off because keeping the voltage boosted when not used wastes quite a bit of power.

If all your devices can run straight on 3.3V you can use a Lithium cell directly with a voltage regulator (and with the normal protection circuitry).

Otherwise you can simulate a button press on the on button with a gpio pin to activate the boost circuitry when you are ready to take your measurements; let he voltage stabilize; use transistors to connect the components to power; take your measurements; disconnect the components and then let the timeout expire after which the voltage will drop again.

Comment: how are you using gpio pin to turn on the power bank, when that power bank is what is powing the arduino

Comment: arduino can survive on 3.3V (which the non boosted cell can provide straight up) and the button often just pull a line low which you can do with a GPIO.